# ILMerge and Visual Studio and PostEvent build

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, post-build-event, ilmerge

Met a problem. VS2013 doesnt allow to merge files into same exe which created after build.

```
"$(SolutionDir)ILMerge\ILMerge.exe" "$(TargetPath)" "$(SolutionDir)..\Lib\Soft.dll" /out:"$(TargetPath)"
```

My idea was to merge built exe with 1 dll (uses in references) and to have the same exe filename.
I can do this without any problem apart of VisualStudio.

But i prefer to do merge exactly in post-build event, and do not change the exe filename.

Is there some workaround ?

PS. I dont want to have a dll in resources, because its used a lot, and its easy to have as usual in references

Comment: what exception/message do you get?

Comment: Here is the nice [approach](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2010/02/03/jeffrey-richter-excerpt-2-from-clr-via-c-third-edition.aspx) Jeffery explained, and it worked for me.

Comment: now i have an error 9009 or MSB3073

Comment: Can't you go via a temporary copy? Copy "$(TargetPath)" to "$(TargetPath).tmp", then run "ILMerge $(TargetPath).tmp ... /out:$(TargetPath)"?

Comment: same error code 1.. i guess VisualStudio blocks this

Comment: Error 9009 means that the EXE could not be located by the OS. Try using relative paths from `$(ProjectDir)` instead - it is more reliable.

Comment: Also, try using MSBuild integration instead of post-build events: https://ilmergemsbuild.codeplex.com/